# Is there limitation of the fields that you can put in your AVRO schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Is there limitation of the fields that you can put in the AVRO schema.

For example can we have an AVRO schema with 1 000 000 fields inside it? Will there be some impact on the performance?

Thank you in advance!

I only saw that we have limitation of the version - 1,000 total schema versions across all subjects based on the confluent documentation https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/stream-governance/packages.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avro does not care.

Kafka itself has a 1MB record size limit, so that will apply at both the schema registry (if you use it), as well as the serialized Kafka records themselves.

Confluent Cloud (or any hosted Kafka solution) also may enforce a payload limit size to their APIs

Comment: Can you be more concrete? So there is basically no limitation in the field, if they do not exceed 1MB?

Comment: Can you? Try to define whatever schema you want, then see if you get a specific error message that can be addressed

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response. It was just a general question if for example we can have an avro schema for example with 1 000 000 000 fields of line code that are describing the message payload, as they had like schema with 10 k line code.
Afterwards the issue was identified as they were using external schema referencing and that was the problem.

Comment: There is a limit on schema size, yes. As answered, Kafka records have a default message size of 1MB. All schemas are stored in a Kafka topic. "Lines / Fields" doesn't matter. "Characters in the schema body" does. Expanded references would add more characters to that schema